# Error in Spring MVC Config File 'mvc:resources'

Tags: xml, spring-mvc

--Config file--cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'mvc:resources' must have no character or element information item [children], because the   type's content type is empty

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">  

     <!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->  
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>  

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dhs.controller">  
    </context:component-scan>  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="viewResolver">  
     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>  
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/staticContents/" mapping="/staticContents/**">  
    </mvc:resources>   

    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/staticContents/" mapping="/staticContents/**">  
</mvc:resources>
```

Remove  and write the above line as

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/staticContents/" mapping="/staticContents/**"/>
```

and there will be no marked error

Answer (score 0):

dhs,

I think you edit to some code.

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

You search to web-app folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

If upgrade is possible, upgrade to spring-mvc 4, this is addressed in spring-mvc 4 e.g. http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd